# Randomly position generated divs throughout a header - Javascript Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a header and I need to randomly position div's that resemble stars throughout the header. I have generated 50 of these 'stars' that are span tags with a class of star. CSS turns the star class into somewhat of a star. But, after I have created these 50 spans, I need to randomly position them throughout my header. I have tried generating a random number and assigning it to the class of star but then all the span's happen to have that margin. I need to use margin-top and margin-left with percentages. I have tried assigning the percent to margin-top and margin-left of the div but nothing seems to position them randomly. You can see the demo on [codepen](http://codepen.io/2021nicholasdeb/pen/GWgGWM?editors=0010). My code:

```
<div class="header" id="head">
<div class="starholder" id="holdstar">

</div>
<div class="top_nav">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
</div>
<div class="text text-center">
    <p id="name">Nick <span id="lastname">D</span</p>
</div>
    <div class="mtn1">
    </div>
    <div class="mtn2">
    </div>
    <div class="mtn3">
    </div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//Name hinge
$("#name").click(function() {
    $(".text").addClass("bounce");
    setTimeout(function() {
            $(".text").removeClass("bounce");
    }, 3000);
});


// create stars and place them at random
function createStar() {

    var holder = document.getElementById("holdstar");

    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            var percent = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    var string = percent + "%"

    var percenttwo = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        var stringtwo = percenttwo + "%";

        var star = document.createElement("span");
        star.className = "star";

$(".star").css({
    "margin-top": string,
    "margin-left": stringtwo
});
        document.getElementById("holdstar").appendChild(star);
    }
};


createStar();

});
```

I have looked around for possible answers but none that directly affects multiple divs, any help is wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what effect you desire exactly, but I can explain why your randomness is not "random" (i.e., why every element has the same `margin` in your CodePen).

Instead of passing `'.star'` as your selector to style the element margins (which selects *every* star), you should be passing the variable `star` that you just created:

```
$(star).css({
  "margin-top": string,
  "margin-left": stringtwo
});
```